# Coldfusion ORM Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion ORM application that uses an oracle sequence as the generator for the primary key field. I have verified that I can access the sequence as the user that ColdFusion is connected to the database as in SQL navigator.

My problem is I am getting the following error when I attempt to saveEntity() on any object

> Root cause :java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

I have tried the syntax below with and without the `akc.` prefix. I do have the akc schema defined in the CFC

```
<cfproperty name="KEY_BREED_PAGE" fieldtype="id" generator="sequence" params="{sequence='akc.seq_breed_page_display'}" />
```

and

```
<cfproperty name="KEY_BREED_PAGE" fieldtype="id" generator="sequence" sequence="akc.seq_breed_page_display" />
```

Any ideas on what I can do to resolve this? The ORM works fine when updating but fails on every attempt to create a new record.

Comment: It might be helpful to do a trace on the Oracle end of things to see what SQL CF is passing to it.

Comment: Got it.... it seems the permissions needed to be modified on the sequence.

Comment: Can you create and select this Answer as correct to close out this question?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar when I didn't have the schema. The only difference between your example and mine is that I have the column attribute set.

```
<cfproperty name="KEY_BREED_PAGE" fieldtype="id" column="KEY_BREED_PAGE" generator="sequence" sequence="akc.seq_breed_page_display" />
```